# How to flag invalid XML comments in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, comments

I'm pretty sure I had warnings with VS2013 when XML comments were wrong. I do not have them with VS2015. I do not have access anymore to the machine with VS2013 and it might have been an extension.

Any way to quickly find those invalids comments?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Some description
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="SearchOptions"></param>
    /// <param name="RemovedArg"></param>   <<-- warning about this
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search(Context SearchOptions)
    {
       [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `XML Documentation File` in Project Properties.

The compiler only parses comments when actually generating that file.